# Access database connection in child thread

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-worker-threads

I have an application that uses `worker_threads`. When the application starts up, I create a connection to the database in the main project, then when I start a thread, is it possible to access that database connection without having to connect to the database in the child thread?

```js
// main.database.ts
export abstract class SqlDatabase {
  private static db: Database;
  static connect(dbPath: string) {
    this.db = new Database(dbPath);
  }
  mutate(sql: string, ...parameters: string[]) {
    const stmt = SqlDatabase.db.prepare(sql);
  }
}


// files.database.ts
class FilesDatabase extends SqlDatabase {
  someFunction(){}
}
export const files = new FilesDatabase();


// index.ts
SqlDatabase.connect('/path/to/sqlite.db');
```

Then I have an action which starts up a `Worker` process:

```js
export function runThread(file: string, args: { [key: string]: any; }) {
  return new Worker(path.resolve(__dirname, './worker.js'), {
    workerData: {
      aliasModule: file,
      ...args
    }
  });
}
```

In the worker process I have something like this:

```js
import { files } from '../../database/files.database';
files.someFunction();
```

When running the process I get the following error message:

> const stmt = SqlDatabase.db.prepare(sql);

Is there a way that I can get access to this database without having to make another connection in the child?

Comment: Why are you using a separate thread when NodeJS supports asynchronous IO anyway?

Comment: Maybe I don't follow, but I am doing some AI work with TensorFlow which does some intensive work which I thought would be best in a thread